# Compile error related to copy assignment operator

Tags: c++

Pretty new to c++ so its probably something simple but the header file I was given declares this method

```
Course operator=(const Course&);
```

When I try to write the method header in my .cpp file, which looks like this

```
Course& Course::operator=(const Course&) {}
```

I get these errors

```
course.cpp:29:9: error: no declaration matches ‘Course& Course::operator=(const Course&)’
   29 | Course &Course::operator=(const Course&) {
      |         ^~~~~~
In file included from course.cpp:9:
course.h:12:10: note: candidate is: ‘Course Course::operator=(const Course&)’
   12 |   Course operator=(const Course&);
```

Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: There's a `note: candidate is: ...`. Have you try that yet?

Comment: @silverfox I thought that I had tried that already but I should've tried it again before making this account, it worked thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a type mismatch between your declaration and implementation. Your declaration returns a `Course` by value, but your implementation returns a `Course&` by reference. The latter is the correct thing for an assignment operator to return.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
// missing the '&' in the header declaration
Course& operator=(const Course&);
```